# AWS Rekognition Custom Labels request object has no usable properties? .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, amazon-rekognition

I am playing around with the new AWS Rekognition libraries available in the .NET SDK. I have an Azure Function App with the following libraries installed:

```
Id                                  Versions                                 ProjectName                                                                                                                                                   
--                                  --------                                 -----------                                                                                                                                                   
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions         {1.0.27}                                 FunctionAppDetectCustomLabels                                                                                                                                 
Microsoft.NETCore.App               {2.1.0}                                  FunctionAppDetectCustomLabels                                                                                                                                 
AWSSDK.Rekognition                  {3.3.103.1}                              FunctionAppDetectCustomLabels
```

I have tried instantiating the rekognition request object, expecting to pass in the model Id, image reference etc, yet there don't appear to be any usable properties for the object? What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ignore me. The correct object to use is `DetectCustomLabelsRequest`

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to call `DetectCustomLabelAsync`, you need to use a `DetectCustomLabelsRequest` object, not an `AmazonRekognitionRequest`. The `DetectCustomLabelsRequest` object has the properties you need. Using this object will allow you to set the Image and the Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the custom model.

Here is a link to the API documentation for the correct request object: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Rekognition/TDetectCustomLabelsRequest.html